# Fixed divs under the bootstrap fixed nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to attach some fixed alerts underneath the `navbar-fixed` navigation bar in bootstrap. My best attempt to this point is to make a `div` positioned at `50px` with `position: fixed;` and `width: 100%`, and to insert the alerts in this div. The problem is that this cuts off the top of my other content the same way that `navbar-fixed` cuts off content when one fails apply padding to the body element.

```
#Alerts
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
}
.alert
{
  top: 0px;
  //position: fixed;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px; // to avoid 'underlapping' the navbar
}
```

Here's a link to a not-working example: http://www.bootply.com/pnEHtLhUBi

My best idea at the moment is to use JS to adjust the `padding-top` value on `body` as alerts are created/destroyed, but this is likely bad for maintenance/readability and I'd prefer to do something more declarative with css.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so you just want a fixed nav right below the nav right? do you care what happens when its in mobile dropdown?

Comment: It should do the same when in mobile dropdown mode. Eg, the alerts display below the nav and are 'stuck' there even if the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there won't be a way to do this without js.

Since if the alert is dynamic, meaning it only appears when its triggers via the [alert method](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-methods)

```
$('#alert-danger').show('slow', function(){
    $('body').addClass('moreMargin')
});
```

you can also remove the moreMargin class from the body when you hide the alert

Answer (score -1):

What about putting it inside the same div as the nav.  When they popup they will push down the other content?

Also, since these are alerts, won't the user already have seen the content that is being covered?  If they want to see it again they can just close the alerts.  Maybe I just misunderstood what you are going for?